# Access Denied when trying to create a key in registry

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, registry, access-denied

Im trying to create a key and writing a dword value to it. 
My code results in access denied. 
My windows user has permission as i can manually add/edit the key.

```
RegistryKey Key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\ExistingKey\NewKey"); 
Key.SetValue("CurrentSlipNumber", CurrentSlipNumber, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

All the solutions i see involve modifying UAC or running my program as administrator. These are not available options.

How can i allow this to modify the registry with only code changes?

Comment: You can not. Operating System prevents your application to modify registry. You should have required privileges to do that.

Comment: @dotctor Then how does every other application i install modify the registry. I dont need to manually run the application as administrator or disable UAC.